# currency conversion function

Tags: currency, currency-rates

Hi we have one US website and one CA website

However, for some reason I have to find a Magento function for currency conversion.
I have CAD want to transfer to USD in the US store view. I did set up the Magento currency conversion rate table as well.

So, how do I call this function out to do the conversion?

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert currency you can use `Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface`.

Module’s block class:

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block;
class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_currency;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $currency,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrencyInterface,
        array $data = []
    )
    {        
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_currency = $currency;        
        $this->_priceCurrencyInterface = $priceCurrencyInterface;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    /**
     * Covert currency code
     *
     * @return It return price according to current store from base currency
     */ 
    public function convertPrice($amount,$currency)
    {
        $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
        return $priceCurrencyObject->convert($amount, $store, $currency);
    }
}
?>
```

To get other currncy info storewise:

```
    // retutn Currency Symbol:
    $this->_currency->getCurrencySymbol();

    // return store base currency code
    $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode();

    // return default store currency code
    $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getDefaultCurrencyCode();

    // return array of installed currencies for the scope
    $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getAllowedCurrencies();

    // return current currency rate
    $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyRate();
```

Template (.phtml) file:

```
echo $block->convertPrice($amount,$currency);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

To set the currency based on the website you have to set the default currency by website from configurations.

Go to

> Admin->Stores->Configuration->General->Currancy Setup

Select the **US Website** from the **Store View** selector from top left of the **Configuration** page and set the

**Default Display Currency** to **US Dollar** and for **Allowed Currencies** only select the **US Dollar**. Check this screenshot.

[image]

Procced the same for the **CA Website**.

Clear the cache and check.